# watch os 2 not waking parent app and changing UITableView of parent

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I have a watch app that is being updated for watch os 2.  The sendmessage does not wake the parent app.  According to the transition documentation is this how you would wake a parent in the background.

*"The iOS app is always considered reachable, and calling this method from your Watch app wakes up the iOS app in the background as needed."*

Has anyone had this problem?  The only way to get data is to have the parent app already open.

Another weird thing is the watch app changes the uitableview for the parent app.  When the -(IBAction)yesterdaySales:(id)sender is called on the watch, it changes the parent app UITableView instead of the watch tableview.

InterfaceController.m

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"
#import "MyRowController.h"
#import "ftDateParser.h"
 @import WatchKit;
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
 @interface InterfaceController() <WCSessionDelegate>
 {
IBOutlet WKInterfaceDevice *it;
BOOL tday;
IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *lblCompany;
}

@end


@implementation InterfaceController
@synthesize myTable = _myTable;
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];

// Configure interface objects here.
if([WCSession isSupported]){
    WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    session.delegate = self;
    [session activateSession];
}


//[self requestInfoPhone];
[self getToday];
}

- (void)willActivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];



}

- (void)didDeactivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
[super didDeactivate];
 }
 -(void)requestInfoPhone{

NSDictionary *dic = @{@"request":@"ySales"};

[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:dic
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo){
                               NSLog(@"The Reply: %@", replyInfo);
                               NSDictionary *location = replyInfo;
                               NSString *name = location[@"label"];
                               NSString *totalSales = location[@"totalSales"];
                               // NSString *test2 = location[@"rowText"];
                               NSMutableArray *sales = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                               NSMutableArray *storeNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                               sales = location[@"rowText"];
                               storeNames = location[@"storeNames"];
                               [self loadTable:sales names:storeNames company:name];
                               [_labelName setText:name];
                               [_labelTotalSales setText:totalSales];
                               tday = YES;
                           }
                           errorHandler:^(NSError *error){
                               NSLog(@"%@", error);
                           }
 ];
 }
 -(void)loadTable:(NSMutableArray*)tester names:(NSMutableArray*)names company:(NSString *)company{
[_myTable setNumberOfRows:[tester count] withRowType:@"row"];

[_labelName setText:company];
for (int i = 0; i < [tester count]; i++) {
    MyRowController *vc  = [_myTable rowControllerAtIndex:i];
[vc.testLabel setText:[ftDateParser currencyFormat: tester[i]]];
    [vc.nameLabel setText:[ftDateParser parseName:names[i]]];
}
[_myTable scrollToRowAtIndex:(0)];
}
-(IBAction)yesterdaySales:(id)sender{
if (tday) {
    [_ydaySales setTitle:@"Today Sales"];
    [self requestInfoPhone];
}
else{
    [_ydaySales setTitle:@"Yesterday Sales"];
    [self getToday];
}

}
   -(void)getToday{

NSDictionary *dic = @{@"request":@"todaySales"};

[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:dic
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo){
                                                                  NSDictionary *location = replyInfo;
                               NSString *name = location[@"label"];
                               NSString *totalSales = location[@"totalSales"];
                               // NSString *test2 = location[@"rowText"];
                               NSMutableArray *sales = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                               NSMutableArray *storeNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                               sales = location[@"rowText"];
                               storeNames = location[@"storeNames"];
                               [self loadTable:sales names:storeNames company:name];
                               [_labelName setText:name];
                               [_labelTotalSales setText:totalSales];
                               tday = YES;
                           }
                           errorHandler:^(NSError *error){
                               NSLog(@"%@", error);
                           }
 ];



}
@end
```

Parent.m

```
-(void)setUpAppForWatch{
done = NO;
if([WCSession isSupported]){
    WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    session.delegate = self;
    [session activateSession];
}
}


 -(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull))replyHandler{
/*UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
dispatch_block_t endBlock = ^ {
    if (identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:identifier];
    }
    identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
};

identifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:endBlock];*/

[self setUpAppForWatch];
[self getTheDate];
startDate = todayDay;
endDate = tomorrow;
//[self getTodaySalesforWatch];
NSString *currency = [ftDateParser currencyFormat:totalSales];
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"label": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Town Crier, Inc."],
                       @"totalSales": currency,
                       @"rowText": storeSalesData,//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currency]
                       @"storeNames":storeNames
                       };

NSString *request = [message objectForKey:@"request"];
if ([request isEqualToString:@"todaySales"]) {
    [self getTodaySalesforWatch];
}
else if ([request isEqualToString:@"ySales"]){
    [self connectToWebService];
}
if (done) {
    replyHandler(dic);
}

}
```

**Edit:**

Maybe the changes to the parent app were happening before, but I didn't know cause the app was running in the background.  Still can't get it to wake the parent app.

Comment: In the phone app, where do you set up and activate WCSession?

Comment: ViewDidLoad but I have tried a couple other places also.

Comment: viewDidLoad is not called when the app is running in the background. Try putting it in the app delegate's didFinishLaunching callback

Comment: I see it work fine in other applications when it is in viewDidLoad.  I bet it is opening the app in the background, but closes it before my method can finish. I remember that from watch os 1.

Comment: We are both correct!  The viewDidLoad is called if the view is the initial controller, but when it is not then it is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You don't link to the source of the quote at the top of your question but it must be referring to the `openParentApplication` method of WatchKit 1. Devices running WatchOS 2.0 cannot call `openParentApplication`.

The method you're implementing in the code in your question is for a WCSession, which only works for immediate communication between a WatchKit app extension and an iOS app *that are both running at the same time*. This method does not cause your iOS app to launch, neither in the background nor in the foreground. Other asynchronous communication methods must be used if both apps are not running at the time.